# How can I use library object?

Tags: go

I have an error.
`Document` is struct object on goquery library.
I can't use it in my code below. How can I do?

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "os"
)

func getLocalFile(filename string) (*Document) { // Error
    f, e := os.Open(FILTER_FILE)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    doc, e := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(f)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    return doc
}

const FILE_NAME = "input.html"
func main() {
    doc := getLocalFile(FILE_NAME)
    println(doc)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Qualified identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers)
>
> A qualified identifier is an identifier qualified with a package name
>   prefix. Both the package name and the identifier must not be blank.
>
> ```
> QualifiedIdent = PackageName "." identifier .
> ```
>
> A qualified identifier accesses an identifier in a different package,
>   which must be imported. The identifier must be exported and declared
>   in the package block of that package.
>
> ```
> math.Sin  // denotes the Sin function in package math
> ```

Use the fully qualified name: `goquery.Document`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func getLocalFile(filename string) *goquery.Document {
    f, e := os.Open(filename)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    doc, e := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(f)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    return doc
}

const FILE_NAME = "input.html"

func main() {
    doc := getLocalFile(FILE_NAME)
    println(doc)
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I need the library name ahead of the object name. My question is cleared up. Thank you for your answer.